# Default values of Class properties

Tags: vb.net, class

I have a class, it looks like this:

```
Public Class DataPoint
    Private _data As Integer
    Private _locInText As Integer
    Private _searchValue As String

    Property Data As Integer
        Get
            Return _data
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _data = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property LocInText As Integer
        Get
            Return _locInText
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _locInText = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property SearchValue As String
        Get
            Return _searchValue
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _searchValue = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I then create another class using this class.

```
Public Class PaintData
    Public Time As TimeSpan
    Public Color As DataPoint
    Public Job As New DataPoint
    Public MaxCurrent As New DataPoint
End Class
```

I want to create default values of some of the properties, namly `SearchValue` and `LocInText`.  To me, it makes sense to do this inside the class definition, because these are essentially constants.

Q1. Should I be doing it this way?  If not, what is the proper technique.

Q2. I can't get the syntax right.  Can you help?

```
Public Class PaintData
    Public Time As TimeSpan
    Public Color As DataPoint
    Public Job As New DataPoint
    Public MaxCurrent As New DataPoint

    Color.LocInText = 4 '<----Declaration expected failure because I'm not in a method
    Job.LocInText = 5 '<----Declaration expected failure because I'm not in a method
End Class
```

Thanks all

Comment: `because these are essentially constants` if thats the case then they should probably be ReadOnly **and** set from the ctor

Comment: Add the initialization in the constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give `DataPoint` a constructor:

```
Public Class DataPoint
    Private _data As Integer
    Private _locInText As Integer
    Private _searchValue As String

    Public Sub New(locInText as Integer)
        _locInText = locInText
    End Sub

    '...
End Class
```

And use that:

```
Public Class PaintData
    Public Time As TimeSpan
    Public Color As New DataPoint(4)
    Public Job As New DataPoint(5)
    Public MaxCurrent As New DataPoint(6)
End Class
```

Alternatively you could use

```
Public Property Color As DataPoint = New DataPoint With {.LocInText = 4}
```

in your class definition.  This syntax is arguably more readable than the constructor syntax.

Comment: While technically accurate, the `With` syntax makes it more clear what is going on - improves readability.

Comment: Yes - just saw your answer, I always forget about that syntax - +1 for you :)

Comment: Cool, just added mine to yours.  No need for two answers to this.

Comment: I went with the `WITH` syntax.  Seemed the most readable to me too.  Thank you.

Comment: What about a situation where you may nave 5 or even 10 different class properties?  Using the `with` and "." (dot) notation when initializing the object would work, but what about accessing those values within the class?  Maybe a builder pattern?